# Like Box Div Code - How to I put it on my website using Dreamweaver....currently does nothing

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

Here is the code that the facebook developer page gave me for my site. I've tried putting it in by itself in the body of my code and with and iframe but cant get it to work. any help is appreciated. thanks

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/lapastabella" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>
```

Comment: Are any JavaScript error messages appearing? Which browser are you using?

Comment: I did not get any error messages when I put this code it. Nothing appears on the page either. I tried putting the code into an iframe and that give me a blank box. Not sure what to do to make this work. I use firefox as my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

To:

```
<div id="facebook-jssdk"></div>
```

It looks like an error with the code they give you.  If you read the code its looking for an object with an id of facebook-jssdk which doesn't exist.